# Take the contents of the tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a next structure in my `button`

```
<button>
  Name
  <svg>
<button>
```

The name changes dynamically. How can I get the contents of the button, without `<svg>`

If I use the `innerHTML` i get all structure

Comment: Get the first `#text` node of the `HTMLButtonElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the structure of the button, you can use `.firstChild` to get at the text node containing the text, then access its `.textContent`.

That is,

```
const button = document.getElementById('button'); // or however you reference the button.
console.log(button.firstChild.textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('button').innerText;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<button>
  Name
  <svg>svgtext</svg>
<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `.innerText` property by the looks of it, but it might be easier if you included this information in a `data-` attribute instead of pulling it from the text.

Comment: Could you get an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you put `Name` in a span with a specified `id` and then get that.

```js
var Name = document.getElementById("btnTxt").innerText;
console.log(Name);
```

```html
<button>
  <span id="btnTxt">Name</span>
  <svg>
<button>
```